# My SPFx compatibility between SPFx & Node.js

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling

Inside my node.js I have the following version:

```
D:\SPFx Systems>nvm list
  * 14.18.1 (Currently using 64-bit executable)
    12.22.7
    10.24.1
    8.17.0
```

And inside my SPFx I have this inside the `package.json`, `"@microsoft/sp-core-library": "1.14.0"`

So are those compatible ?

Second question: Also seems there is node.js version 16, so should I install it and use it instead of version 14?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, Node.js v14 and SPFx v1.14 are compatible with each other.

Check detailed SPFx compatibility matrix at: [SPFx development environment compatibility](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/compatibility)

---

Answer to your 2nd question:

Node.js v14 is the currently recommended version use with the SharePoint Framework v1.14. So, continue using it instead of downloading Node.js v16.

The SharePoint Framework v1.14.0 is supported on the following Node.js versions:

- Node.js v12.13.0+ (Erbium)
- Node.js v14.15.0+ (Fermium)

Comment: thanks for the help